# Looping through stock market API using python

Tags: python

i want you want loop through the result from yahoo finance api to return the company name and stock prices for top gainers.

```
    import requests
    import pprint


    url = "https://yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com/api/yahoo/ga/topgainers"

    querystring = {"start":"0"}

 headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "9efd0f3e52mshd859f5daf34a429p11cb2ajsn2b0e421d681e"
      }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    new_response = response.text




    def new_stock(one_stock):
       arranged = []
      for items in (one_stock):
        new_name = dict.get("regularMarketPrice")
        result = arranged.append(one_stock)
        return result

   print(new_stock(new_response))
```

but it keeps returning this error

```
      'File "monitor.py", line 27, in <module>
           print(new_stock(new_response))
          File "monitor.py", line 23, in new_stock
           new_name = dict.get("regularMarketPrice")
           TypeError: descriptor 'get' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'str'
```

Comment: first see `print(response.text)` . If you expected JSON data then you may have to use module `json` to convert string to dictionary. or use `new_response = response.json()`

Comment: you should also check what you get in dictionary - you get nested dictionary. If value is in `data["A"]["B"]["regularMarketPrice"]` then you can't get it directly using `.get("regularMarketPrice")` but you have to use `["A"]["B"]["regularMarketPrice"]`

Comment: BTW: `append()` doesn't create new list and it returns `None` so `result = arranged.append(one_stock)` means `result = None` and you shoud use `return arranged` instead of `return result`

Comment: other mistake - you should `append(new_name)`, not `append(one_stock)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few mistakes

---

If you expect JSON data then use `response.json()` instead of `response.text`

```
data = response.json()
```

`.text` gives string which you would have to convert to python dictionary using module `json`

```
import json

data = json.loads(response.text)
```

---

You get nested data and you need to use `data['quotes']` to get list with results.

```
for item in data['quotes']:
    #print(item.keys())

    name = item.get("shortName")
    price = item.get("regularMarketPrice")
```

---

`append()` doesn't create new list and it returns `None so

```
 result = arranged.append(one_stock)
```

means

```
 result = None
```

You should use

```
arranged.append(one_stock)
```

and later

```
return arranged
```

And you should append value which you get, not `one_stock`

```
arranged.append( (name, price) )
```

---

Working code

```
import requests
import pprint

# --- functions ---

def new_stock(data):
    result = []

    for item in data['quotes']:
        #print(item.keys())
        name = item.get("shortName")
        price = item.get("regularMarketPrice")

        result.append((name, price))

    return result

# --- main ---

url = "https://yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com/api/yahoo/ga/topgainers"

querystring = {"start":"0"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "9efd0f3e52mshd859f5daf34a429p11cb2ajsn2b0e421d681e"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
data = response.json()

#pprint.pprint(data)

pprint.pprint(new_stock(data))
```

Result:

```
[('ROLLS ROYCE HOLDINGS NON CUM RE', 0.0048),
 ('CIELO SA', 0.914),
 ('ASX LTD', 51.45),
 ('FLIR Systems, Inc.', 42.735),
 ('EQUATORIAL ENERGIA SA', 3.87),
 ('LOCALIZA RENT A CAR SA', 6.961),
 ('ADYEN NV UNSPON ADS EACH REP 0.', 18.64),
 ('Beyond Meat, Inc.', 84.35),
 ('SIKA AG', 17.025),
 ('Equifax, Inc.', 133.01),
 ('FUJI ELECTRIC CO. LTD.', 5.88),
 ('New Residential Investment Corp', 5.265),
 ('ENAGAS SA', 10.8301),
 ('THAI BEVERAGE PUBLIC COMPANY LT', 0.4749),
 ('ManpowerGroup', 64.61),
 ('Viela Bio, Inc.', 40.8),
 ('BANCO ACTINVER SA', 0.8351),
 ('Simmons First National Corporat', 18.3182),
 ('Suzano S.A.', 6.75),
 ('New Oriental Education & Techno', 113.04),
 ('PEUGEOT SA', 12.7148),
 ('The Madison Square Garden Compa', 237.22),
 ('FLUTTER ENTERTAINMENT PLC UNSPO', 56.65)]
```